# Apply curve_fit within a loop

Tags: python, pandas

as indcated, I have a problem with fitting a function to data within a loop. This is a groupby object out of a dataframe. This groupby object has the following structure:

```
    f [MHz] T [K]   Rs
0   400 1.75    13.472493
1   400 2.00    14.054298
2   400 2.25    14.900821
3   400 2.50    16.453007
4   400 2.75    18.050460
13  800 1.75    36.008499
14  800 2.00    37.924344
15  800 2.25    41.246962
16  800 2.50    45.780308
17  800 2.75    51.904333
26  1200    1.75    53.809458
27  1200    2.00    61.427391
28  1200    2.25    67.438682
29  1200    2.50    75.302240
30  1200    2.75    88.015202
```

Now, I would like to apply a fit to each frequency group (400, 800 and 1200) and do this efficiently within a loop. The first attempt is:

```
i = 0
for freq, grp1 in RT1.groupby(['f [MHz]']):
    T[i] = grp1['T [K]'].values[condition]
    Rs[i]= grp1['Rs'].values[condition]
    popt[i], pcov[i] = curve_fit(RsT, T[i], Rs[i], p0)
    figure = plt.figure()
    grp1.plot(x = 'T [K]',y = 'Rs', color = colors[i], marker = markers[i] , ls = 'None', title = 'R(T) {f} MHz with Fit'.format(f = freq)) 
    plt.plot(T[i], RsT(T[i], *popt[i]), label = 'fit')
    i += 1
```

i runs from 0 to 2 to create T1, Rs1; T2, Rs2 and so on. The condition constrains the T values to a certain range and this seems to work properly. However, I could not manage to adress the curv_fit routine properly to all three frequency groups - it raises the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-0b3b4adc65e7> in <module>()
     24 i = 0
     25 for freq, grp1 in RT1.groupby(['f [MHz]']):
---> 26     T[i] = grp1['T [K]'].values[condition]
     27     Rs[i]= grp1['Rs'].values[condition]
     28     popt[i], pcov[i] = curve_fit(RsT, T[i], Rs[i], p0)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The problem is, that I fail to assign three different arrays for T and Rs for each group - I would like to have T1 and Rs1 with the values for 400 MHz, T2 and Rs2 with the values of 800 MHz and so on. Also, popt and pcov should be calculated three times separately (popt1, pcov1; pop2, pcov2; ...) corresponding to a separate fit on each data group.
I hope, that there is someone, who could explain, if it is possible to apply the curv_fit routine within a loop and if so - how.
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show the definition of your function "RsT" or just the entire code you are using!?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all replys and suggestions so far! The definition of the function is:

Comment: RsT = (a/T)*np.e**(b/T) + c

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `T` and `RsT` are NumPy arrays with a *non-object dtype*. Trying to assign an array of values to one cell of `T` raises the ValueError you are seeing:

```
In [117]: T = np.zeros(3)

In [118]: T[0] = np.arange(10)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

You could use an array of object dtype

```
In [119]: T = np.zeros(3, dtype='O')

In [120]: T[0] = np.arange(10)

In [121]: T
Out[121]: array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

but object arrays are not particularly fast; you would do just as well making `T` and `RsT` lists.